# Under case statement else part is giving incorrect output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query where I think my condition is true but somehow it is giving incorrect output.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'd' THEN SecDebit END AS 'debit',
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN SecCredit END AS 'credit',docdate,DATEDIFF(d,DocDate, GETDATE()) AS days,
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 365  THEN SecDebit ELSE 
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN -seccredit ELSE 0 END END AS 'secdebitlessthen365',
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) > 365 AND DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 730  THEN SecDebit  ELSE 
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN -seccredit ELSE 0 END END AS 'secdebitgreaterthen365lessthenorequa730',
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) > 730 AND DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 1095  THEN SecDebit ELSE 
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN -seccredit ELSE 0 END END AS 'secdebitgreaterthen730lessthenorequal1095',
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) > 1095 THEN SecDebit ELSE 
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN -seccredit ELSE 0 END END AS 'secdebitgreaterthen1095'
FROM J_Transactions (NOLOCK) j
WHERE AccountID IN (871446)
AND j.DocTypeID=0
```

Only for credit my else statement is going wrong

My output is

```
debit       credit      days    secdebit<365    secdebit>365<=730   secdebit>730<=1095  secdebit>1095   
24196.5000  NULL        783     0.0000         0.0000           24196.5000      0.0000    
NULL        24471.6500  418    -24471.6500     0.0000           -24471.6500     -24471.6500    
NULL        10.5800     418    -10.5800        0.0000           -10.5800        -10.5800
```

For credit both days is 418 which should come under secdebit>365<=730 but instead it is coming in every where except the correct one. Can someone tell me what is wrong in this

Desired output

```
debit       credit      days    secdebit<365    secdebit>365<=730   secdebit>730<=1095  secdebit>1095      
24196.5000  NULL        783     0.00           0.0000               24196.5000          0.00      
NULL        24471.6500  418     0.00          -24471.65             0.00                0.00   
NULL        10.5800     418     0.00          -10.5800              0.00                0.00
```

Comment: Pls post your desired output

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to rewrite your entire query, but I believe you want to modify you case statements to follow a structure more like this:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 365 THEN 
    CASE WHEN CreditOrDebit = 'd' THEN SecDebit 
    ELSE -seccredit END
ELSE 0 END AS 'secdebitlessthan365'
```

Comment: great this is what I wanted!!!! Appreciated your reply on this. Thank you !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can not understand your business logic. Based upon the code  You provided, the problem is "Else" statement doesn't have the Days checking logic. I have added the same.
Please try it out.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'd' THEN SecDebit END AS 'debit',
CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN SecCredit END AS 'credit',
docdate,
DATEDIFF(d,DocDate, GETDATE()) AS days,
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(d,DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 365  THEN 
        CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN
            -seccredit 
        ELSE
            SecDebit
        END
END AS 'secdebitlessthen365',

CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) > 365 AND DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 730  THEN 
        CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN
            -seccredit 
        ELSE
            SecDebit
        END
END AS 'secdebitgreaterthen365lessthenorequa730',

CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) > 730 AND DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) <= 1095  THEN 
       CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN
            -seccredit 
        ELSE
            SecDebit
        END
END AS 'secdebitgreaterthen730lessthenorequal1095',
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(d, DocDate, GETDATE()) > 1095 THEN 
        CASE WHEN j.DocTypeID=0 AND CreditOrDebit = 'c' THEN
            -seccredit 
        ELSE
            SecDebit
        END
END AS 'secdebitgreaterthen1095'
FROM J_Transactions (NOLOCK) j
WHERE AccountID IN (871446)
AND j.DocTypeID=0
```